# Nested views in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have a container view which, among other things, displays a list of objects, like so:

```
 {{#each}}
      <div {{bind-attr class="author.first_name task"}}></div>
 {{/each}}
```

I would like to hook a Javascript function everytime a DOM element is added to this list. I've tried doing:

```
didInsertElement: function() { ... }
```

But this hook apparently runs only the first time the view is initialized. I figured that maybe the hook doesn't run because the view is actually inserted once, and what's inserted more than once are just the nested element.

So should I use a **nested view**?

I tried something along these lines:

```
{{#each}}
     {{#view App.SingleItemView}}
         <div {{bind-attr class="author.first_name task"}}></div>
     {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

But in this case, though it works somehow, it doesn't get passed the necessary data that would render the properties such as `author.first_name`.

Comment: I was confused by this when I first approached Ember too. In short, yes, use a nested view. The [template-helpers guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/) has useful info, specifically at the bottom where it shows the context each helper is using. When using `view` you can specify the model binding, such as `{{view App.AuthorView authorBinding=this}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

render will give you a new scope and is really easy to assign the content as well

```
<ul>
  {{#each item in controller}}
    {{render 'ind' item}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/alAKubo/1/edit

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work thanks to this. I guess the parameters for the helpers are a bit confusing.

Comment: Ah, related question: should I extend the `CollectionView` or the normal `View`? I am using the normal view and it works, but I guess I should use the former: what are the advantages of either?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you're talking with, feel free to use the jsbin I already gave you.

Comment: Not sure what kind of example I could give you, I modified the JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/alAKubo/3/edit. Basically the IndexView contains the single Vies that are rendered through `render`. Should IndexView be a CollectionView or a normal View. Additionally, and I just realized with the example, why can I call `color` on the template correctly, but if I call it on the view it is undefined?

Comment: color is an undefined variable, it's the same as calling foo, or john, or bar, they aren't defined.  color lives on the model, which is proxied through the controller, so you should be using a getter.  Collection views are useful when you are programmatically injecting views, beside that they aren't super useful from the template.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/alAKubo/4/edit

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful; I had tried with `this.get('controller').color`, but it had not worked. As for CollectionView, I don't want to keep you any longer, but I still don't get it, the docs say: “Ember.CollectionView is [...] responsible for managing a collection [...] by maintaining a child view object and associated DOM representation for each item in the array and ensuring that child views and their associated rendered HTML are updated when items in the array are added, removed, or replaced.” but I seem to be able to do that with a regular view.

Comment: Yeah, if you are strictly creating a collection of views, but it's significantly easier to allow ember to control the collection (adding, removing etc) and just use the template helpers (render, partial etc) for building up your view.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the time. I guess I'll go with the regular View then and I'll postpone the learning of the CollectionView for a more advanced level. Thanks again. I'll keep sweating over Ember.